# Use std::find with stride and only check specific member in struct

Tags: algorithm, c++11, vulkan

`layers` stores a lot of members, like each element's name:

```cpp
std::vector<vk::LayerProperties> layers = vk::enumerateInstanceLayerProperties()
```

`layerNames` only stores the name of each layer:

```cpp
std::vector<const char*> layerNames(layers.size());
```

I copy the name member from each `layer` element into `layerNames`,
and then use `std::find` on `layerNames`.

Is there a way to use `std::find` on `layers` directly and use a stride to only check the name member when iterating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for something like this:

```
auto it = std::find_if(layers.begin(), layers.end(),
  [&name_to_look_for](const vk::LayerProperties& layer) {
    return layer.name == name_to_look_for;
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for